# Exporting Drupal 6 to Wordpress latest (3.2.1?)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, drupal, drupal-6, export

I have inherited a website in Drupal. Cut a long painful story short: I want desperately to move to sanity. WP 3.2.1 (latest as of this writing) is the choice.

Yet, it looks like the export process in Drupal requires a PhD in mechanical engineering. Googling for something results in a Java program (out of question for us) or a paid service.

Really? Is there no humane way to move all my data from Drupal to WP?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: The way data is organized in a Drupal site can differ massively from the relatively primitive structure of a Blog, especially if you're using a lot of custom data types and such. Needs more info about the web site you're trying to export I think. And are you really sure this is the right way to go in the first place? Why do you want to leave Drupal?

Comment: WP is not a "blog" anymore. I can create any website with WP as backend. Anyway, let's presume that Drupal's default install was used. All I need is the content + dates + basic fields. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka +1 for "Why do you want to leave Drupal?"...who would?!

Comment: @PKHunter If you've had a bad experience with Drupal 6 you might want to check out Drupal 7, there's a world of difference; it's actually quite easy to administer now, and an absolute joy to code on top of.

Comment: Check the java program available here: http://modeling-languages.com/migrating-drupal-6-to-wordpress-3/ for a basic migration

Comment: @Clive, I looked at Drupal 7. Downloaded it on my personal machine and played with it. It certainly looks like a world apart from its ugly v6 cousin, but the node and modules stuff is still far from ideal, and the plugins are surely targeted at folks who want to spend time developing. WP has clean, beautiful, simple looking stuff (from BBpress forums to buddypress to ecommerce JigoShop etc) so it works for us. We can start our site by next morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WP **is** still only properly effective as a blogging platform no matter what they want to tell you (trust me I have a lot of experience in this area). Various people have extended upon its core functionality so that it *can* do more than it originally did, but these extensions are strained at best. Drupal was built specifically to be extended, and thus we developers can extend it painlessly.

That being said though (and with my mini-rant out of the way!), this bit of SQL will start you off...it will pull in the basic content from the `node` table to the wordpress `wp_posts` table.

```
INSERT INTO wp23.wp_posts (
ID, post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_name, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, post_type)

SELECT node.nid, node.uid, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created), FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created), node_revisions.body, node.title, node_revisions.teaser, concat('node/', node.nid), FROM_UNIXTIME(node.changed), FROM_UNIXTIME(node.changed),'page'
FROM drupal.node, drupal.node_revisions WHERE node.type = 'page' AND node.nid = node_revisions.nid
```

Unfortunately there is no easy way to automatically pull in CCK (D6) or core (D7) fields because field storage is vastly different in Drupal/Wordpress; you'll have to examine the tables and write a custom script depending on the fields you have added.

Hope that helps

These links will probably help out too, the first one is where the above SQL came from:

[How To Migrate From Drupal To WordPress — Export And Import Mysql Script](http://www.binaryturf.com/migrate-drupal-wordpress-export-import-mysql-script/)
[Migrating Drupal to Wordpress](http://rufuspollock.org/2005/10/10/migrating-drupal-to-wordpress/)

Comment: Nice job, man. You should take another look at the 3.2 WP releases, though. A lot has changed in the recent past, including custom post type support. WP has in fact grown into a decent CMS framework.

Comment: I stand corrected :-) I had heard the latest Wordpress incorporates some sort of field-based system, didn't know they were finally splitting the post types down. Thumbs up to Wordpress! Don't get me wrong from my rant above as well, I think Wordpress (prior to 3.2) it excellent for what it is, I just never saw it as particularly extensible.

Comment: WOW, Clive, that's just what I needed! Thanks for those two URLs! 

Let me add this for Google to pick up this page when someone like me is searching for this info in the future: Migrate from Drupal to Wordpress,  Migrate from Drupal to Wordpress, Migrate from Drupal to Wordpress.

Although I have to say, WP in 3.2.1 is a massive different platform, and frankly a charm to customize. Everyone, especially simple users who use the CMS for content uploading, LOVE the customized UI. For me, templating the frontend is painfully simple. Hope I'm right in 2 years. Who knows. But THANKS for now!